# Sort category posts in Wordpress by meta key

Tags: php, wordpress

I will try to make this as short and clear as possible.

**What is my goal?**

My goal is to sort posts in my category page by meta key. I have a category named "Rating" and each post in that category has a meta key named "Rating" - in it is a numerical value.

So, for example, I have "Restaurant A" and "Restaurant B" in category "Rating". One has meta key "Rating" value of 56, the other one 40. I would like to show them from the highest rating to the lowest rating (not alphabetically, chronologically or any other way.)

**What have I tried?**

I have tried adding this directly into my category.php file:

```
<?php global $query_string;
$posts = query_posts('posts_per_page=5&cat=rating&meta_key=rating&order=ASC'); 
?>
```

before this part, which was already in *category.php* file:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php fotomag_post_layout(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and ended the code with this part:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**How did I fail?**

It partially works. It does show, for example, 5 posts and if I delete meta key from some of the posts in the "Rating" category it doesn't show them here (which is correct - because the query is to show posts in Rating category which have a Rating metafield). But it does not order it by ascending or descending means.

*What am I doing wrong?* Should I put any kind of filter or action hook or something in my functions file? Is something messing up with my theme? (I have no other plugins installed by the way)

**Additional files:**

My functions.php file (with the add_action hook mentioned in the answer below) - https://pastebin.com/WYyRknD6

My category.php file - https://pastebin.com/nWFgL1bV

My post layout file (this is the file that gets called in the category.php file - it maybe is or isn't relevant) - https://pastebin.com/3M6mrQVY

You can check the live version of the page here - https://preprod.pojej.me/category/rating/ - the number shown on the post is the number value in the "Rating" meta key field (minus the % symbol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of that, you'll want to use the [pre_get_posts filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) to modify the main query and have it return posts ordered by your meta field. This way, if you want to extend this functionality to other categories (or taxonomies) later you'll only need to change the code in one place.

For example:

```
function wp87615486_custom_sort_rating_category( $query ) {

    /**
     * Modify the 'rating' category main query
     * to have it sort posts by meta rating value.
     */
    if (
        is_category( 'rating' ) // we're currently viewing the 'rating' category
        && !is_admin() // and we're not in the admin
        && $query->is_main_query() // and this is WP's main query
    ) {

        $posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $posts_per_page );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_lets_review_final_score' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' ); // ASC will return entries with the lowest rating, DESC the ones with the higher rating

    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wp87615486_custom_sort_rating_category' );
```

Then you can use the regular [loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) in category.php.

Comment: Hi @cabrerahector. Thank you for your answer and for modifying it so it fits my question. So, if I'm correct - I put this into functions.php file and nothing in category.php (well, nothing custom added, I just leave the file intact as it came with the theme) and when a user visits the category page for 'Rating' it should work? Just double-checking so I don't mess it up.

Comment: Yes, that's basically the idea :)

Comment: Your code could be written up perfectly, but it won't work on my theme. I added it into the functions.php file (you can check it in the file I added to my queston) but the sorting doesn't happen.

Comment: Hey @HarisMustajbasic. Thanks for sharing your code, that helped figure out what the problem is: you're using the wrong meta key. The plugin you're using saves the score in a post meta called `_lets_review_final_score`. In your code (which I used as a base) you're using `review`. I updated my answer accordingly, it should work now.

Comment: I have added the code in my functions.php file but it still won't update it alphabetically. I have a hunch that your code would work on another site, but it doesn't on mine :( Could this have something to do with the post layout template or something like that?

Comment: Alphabetically? You said: "My goal is to sort posts in my category page by meta key (...) (not alphabetically, chronologically or any other way)." This code does exactly that (I actually tested it with the Twenty Seventeen theme and the LetsReview plugin and it worked as expected).

Comment: Sorry, I meant it won't update it from the highest to the lowest rating. That means something must be wrong with my theme. Due to the fact that the code is correct and serves it purpose I will choose it as best answer, even if it doesn't really solve my problem (but that one is on my side somewhere, I just need to find it).

Comment: Try switching to another theme (eg. Twenty Seventeen) and check again. If it works with a different theme, then it definitely is something from your theme that's preventing the sorting from working as expected. Otherwise it could be a plugin causing the conflict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171010/discussion-between-haris-mustajbasic-and-cabrerahector).